# java - HttpClient : How to send post request to page that auto generate random field name?

Tags: java, httpclient

A page is auto generating random name every time for a text input field. How can I get this name before executing post request, so I can use that name at time of adding post parameters in ArrayList<NameValuePair>.

Comment: a bit of code snippet would do better, right ?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11926733/  - please don't laugh at the code :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using regex. The file name has pattern of 6 character capital characters. So I used this regex :

```
.*id=\"([A-Z]{6}).*
```